# HandlerInterceptor preHandle is not called when resides with Spring-security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, interceptor

I'm trying to add `HandlerInterceptor preHandle` method to log some request params into designated file in my file-system.

My service also uses Spring-Security (I have a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) for authentication and ignores particular resource via `webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**")`

My `HandlerInterceptor` ('`MyHandlerInterceptor.class`') is registered to `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` by `addInterceptors`, and both `MyWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `MyWebMvcConfigurerAdapter` are provided to the root application context by `getRootConfigClasses()`.

It seems that `MyHandlerInterceptor` catches requests from "`/resources/**`" and not for other paths. I suspect that this has to be related to the fact that this path is ignored by spring security authentication. Any idea how to resolve this?

P.S., It is worth mentioning that I set my interceptor to by applied on all paths = `registry.addInterceptor(new MyHandlerInterceptor().addPathPatterns("/**"));`